# Can I add UIImage or CGImageRef to video?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, uiimage, avfoundation

I want to add an image in between videos, just like smiley or clip art. Smiley and Clip art most probably has animation.

I referred to  [Find assets in library - add to a AVMutableComposition - export = crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579315/find-assets-in-library-add-to-a-avmutablecomposition-export-crash) and also Apple's `ALAssetLibrary`. but could not get any ideas to complete my requirement.

Is there any functionality to add `UIImage`s and `CGImageRef`s to an `AVMutableComposition`?

How can I add an image into a video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been done with CALayer.

If anyone wants to add UIImage in video file than please add as a CALayer,

also add textlayer..

many thanks to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video#7205820)

Cheers..... :)